# May I ask what the syntax of "-1" in the random effect term of the glmer() formula mean?

Tags: regression, time-series, mathematical-statistics, lme4-nlme

I am replicating ones' time course analysis with a glmer() formula built like:

```
optionval ~ nt1 + nt2 + nt3 + section:(nt1+nt2+nt3) + (nt1-1|participant.id)
```

nts are natural polynomial terms. What I don't understand is the syntax of "`-1`" here. Generally, I just see people use the kind like `nt1|factor` as the random effect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's removing the random intercept that would be associated with `participant`; intercepts are assumed in R's formulas so `(x | subject)` implies a random intercept per subject plus a random slope of covariate `x`. Using `(0 + x | subject)` of `(x - 1 | subject)` suppresses this intercept.

Comment: @GavinSimpson thank you so much. It is great to know that - 1 equals +0 for random effects. May I further ask if there is any default intercept for fixed effects?

Comment: Yes; the intercept is also implied in the "fixed" effects - you'll see it listed in the model summary.